# How to avoid an encoding process

Tags: bash, encoding, utf-8, ascii

I've been trying to pass a *us-ascii* encoded file to an *utf-8* encoded file. However, I've read that *us-ascii* format is a subset of *utf-8* and for that reason bash is not really allowing me to pass from *us-ascii* to *utf-8*.

What my code does is that if my file is already in *utf-8*, then a message is printed. Else, the encoding process to *utf-8* is done and this new file is named: *file_encoded.psv*. Since my original file is in *us-ascii* format then my code tries to pass from *us-ascii* to *utf-8* but, as mentioned before, since *us-ascii* is a subset of *utf-8* bash is not allowing me to do this transformation, but my output file is: *file_encoded.psv* although no encoding is being done.

```
# getting encoding format
encoding=`file -i $file | sed 's/=/ /g' |awk '{print $4}'`

# if file is already in utf-8 format then no transformation is needed
if [ ! "$encoding" == "utf-8" ]; then
        # getting file's extension
        extension2=`echo $outputfile | sed 's/\./ /g' | awk '{print $2}'`;
        query2="s/\.$extension2//g"

        # filename without dot
        new_output=`echo $outputfile | sed -e $query2`

        # declaring file output name
        new_outputfile=`echo "${new_output}_encoded.psv"`

        # from original format to utf-8
        iconv -f $encoding -t UTF-8//TRANSLIT $outputfile -o $new_outputfile

        # delete old file
        rm $outputfile

else
        echo "Document is already in utf-8 format"
fi
```

To fix this I've add an *OR* statement to my code so what my code should do is: if the file is not in *us-ascii* or *utf-8* encoding format, then do the encoding; else print a message. However, although my file is in *us-ascii* the encoding process is intended to be performed.

```
# getting encoding format
encoding=`file -i $file | sed 's/=/ /g' |awk '{print $4}'`

# if file is already in utf-8 format then no transformation is needed
if [ ! "$encoding" == "utf-8" ] || [ ! "$encoding" == "us-ascii" ]; then
        # getting file's extension
        extension2=`echo $outputfile | sed 's/\./ /g' | awk '{print $2}'`;
        query2="s/\.$extension2//g"

        # filename without dot
        new_output=`echo $outputfile | sed -e $query2`

        # declaring file output name
        new_outputfile=`echo "${new_output}_encoded.psv"`

        # from original format to utf-8
        iconv -f $encoding -t UTF-8//TRANSLIT $outputfile -o $new_outputfile

        # delete old file
        rm $outputfile

else
        echo "Document is already in utf-8 format"
fi
```

Comment: How do you know that no encoding has been done? If you encode ASCII into UTF-8, you get what you put in.

Comment: Yes, us-ascii is a perfect subset of utf-8. Every us-ascii encoded value is a legal utf-8 encoding with the same meaning, so there is no need to convert it. What problem are you encountering? What do you mean by "bash is not really allowing me to pass from us-ascii to utf-8." What  symptom are you seeing? Are you certain that the input file is actually ASCII, and not one of the numerous "extended ASCII" formats? ASCII data will have no values greater than 127. https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/charsets/US-ASCII

Comment: I'm using this line of code `file -i filename | sed 's/=/ /g' |awk '{print $4}'` to know the encoding format of a file. I've tried it before with other formats and it works well. While testing that line of code with the file I'm working the output is *us-ascii*, that's it, that's the output. So I decided to add another statement to my *if-else* so if my file is in us-ascii or utf-8 a message is printed, if my file IS NOT in us-ascii or utf-8 then the encoded process should be done but although my file is in us-ascii the encoding is tried to be done and the name of the file is changed.

Comment: Apparently the if statement is not working correctly. It seems like it doesn't "know" that my file is already in us-ascii and for that reason the encoding process is done.

Comment: Unrelated: Instead of `file -i filename | sed 's/=/ /g' |awk '{print $4}'` do `file -i adventure.cpp | awk -F= '{ print $NF }'` - Yes, it says it's `us-ascii` because it is. It's also UTF-8. All valid `us-ascii` is valid UTF-8, but not all valid UTF-8 is valid `us-ascii`. So, if you have a file in `us-ascii` you never need to convert it to UTF-8. It already is in UTF-8.

Comment: I know I don't need to convert it to UTF-8 but for some reason my code is doing it. I know it because if the encoding process is done my output file is: *filename_encoded.psv* but if the encoding process is not done, then the output file should be: *filename.psv*. But I'm getting *filename_encoded.psv*.